# How much data can be copied to a publisher in postgres logical replication

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

Logical replication copies a snapshot of the data on the publisher database. I want to find out how much data can be copied to the publisher at once.

Comment: I don't think there is any limitation

Comment: Thanks for the reponse